# Document.WithSourceCodeKind(SourceCodeKind.Script) vs CSharpScript.Create

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am working on a script editor that can provide code completion and on-the-fly compilation diagnostics. I started using CSharpScript.Create:

```
this._script = CSharpScript.Create<T>(sourceCode,ScriptOptions.Default,typeof(T));
diagnostics = this._script.Compile().ToList();
```

but noticed that the memory consumption was increasing at each script creation (triggered by source code modification). Then i looked upon using Document:

```
this.Document = this.Workspace
    .AddProject("TestProject", LanguageNames.CSharp)
    .WithMetadataReferences(...)
    .AddDocument("", "")
    .WithSourceCodeKind(SourceCodeKind.Script);

diagnostics=this.Document.WithText(SourceText.From(sourceCode)).GetSemanticModelAsync()
    .Result.GetDiagnostics().ToList()
```

Memory consumption stays low but I don't know how to pass global variable information  as easily than with CSharpScript.Create. Any reference to a global variable inside the script triggers a CS0103 error - "The name '' does not exist in the current context".

Is it possible with a document to pass global variable type information ?

How can we execute such a document / script ? (currently I am using CSharpScript.Create to compile and execute code, and Workspace / Document to provide code completion).

Comment: The extra stuff (& memory) for `CSharpScript` does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: how does this compile `CSharpScript.Create<T>sourceCode,ScriptOptions.Default,typeof(T));` are you missing an open (

Comment: @johnny5 Sorry for the bad copy/paste.

Comment: It's okay I just wanted to make sure before I editted it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548780/roslyn-is-it-possible-to-pass-variables-to-documents-with-sourcecodekind-scrip